# asp.net mvc Overriding CreateController of DefaultContollerFactory?

Tags: controller, factory

`public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)`

Is it normal that the controllerName passed into this function is sometimes
"content"?

how can i avoid that?

```
 public override IController CreateController(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
        {
            var controllerType = GetControllerType(controllerName);

            var projectType = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Sales"];

            if (controllerType.BaseType == Type.GetType(projectType))
            {
                var salesid = requestContext.RouteData.Values["salesid"];
                int intValue;
                int.TryParse(salesid.ToString(), out intValue);

                if (intValue == 0)
                    throw new FormatException("salesid is missing");

                return Activator.CreateInstance(controllerType, int.Parse(salesid.ToString())) as IController;
            }

            return base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        }
```

The controllerName being passed here is sometimes "Content".
I just thought that it should be controller name.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal that the controllerName passed into this function is sometimes "content"?

Not sure what you mean *sometimes*.
You must have ContentController and when an action of this controller is invoked controller name will be "content"/"Content".

> how can i avoid that?

I do not see any reason you need to avoid having name of the controller in controllerName parameter.